# Applying bindingRedirect config to pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, .net, app-config, python.net

I have an application that relies on NuGet's `<bindingRedirect>` feature to ensure a single version of log4net.dll. Binding redirects are automatically added to the applications app.config file.

I'd like to load that application's assemblies into Python and call into its code, but because the binding redirects are application-specific, they're not being picked up by Pythonnet and the assembly fails to load:

```
LOG: Post-policy reference: log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
[...snip...]
LOG: Assembly Name is: log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
```

Can I get pythonnet to refer to my application's app.config and use the `<bindingRedirect>` found there? Or can I apply a binding redirect after startup, without needing an app.config?

Comment: Are you using .NET assemblies from Python or embedding Python in .NET?

Comment: I'm calling .NET assemblies from Python

Comment: Then `app.config` should apply to `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Copying over the app.config is like a global solution to a local problem (one python.exe, lots of apps needing bindingRedirects), but it gets me past this problem and I can't think of a better way.

Comment: another solution would be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33362587/2230844

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to enable `app.config` with pythonnet when using .NET assemblies from CPython:

Place `python.exe.config` file next `python.exe` with the following configuration for detection later:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="customAppSettingsGroup">
          <section name="customAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <customAppSettingsGroup>
        <customAppSettings>
          <add key="Debugger" value="True"/>
        </customAppSettings>
    </customAppSettingsGroup>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>`

Generate .NET assembly with the following code for testing and reading app.config settings:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;

namespace dotnet20
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            NameValueCollection settings =
                ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings") as NameValueCollection;

            if (settings != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in settings.AllKeys)
                {
                    if ((key == "Debugger") && (settings[key] == "True"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Detected debugger mode");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now test that pythonnet is able to detect these custom settings from app.config:

```
python
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r"C:\pythonnet\dotnet2.0\bin\Debug")
>>> clr.AddReference("dotnet2.0")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x000001A51626D630>
>>> from dotnet20 import Class1
>>> Class1()
Detected debugger mode
<dotnet20.Class1 object at 0x000001A51626D6A0>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got into similar problem using Pythonnet with .net dLLs.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I didn't have Version 3.1.0.0 of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` and hence the error. My .net project has `app.config` file which was pointing to a newer version of this dependency ( 3.1.5.0) [ bindingRedirect ]

The solution was to use this `app.config` file from .net project, rename it to `python.exe.config` and put it in the same folder where python.exe is. I am not sure if this is the best solution but i have looked in to a bunch of other solutions and this only seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyinstaller` (to install with pip: `pip install pyintaller` see [project page](https://www.pyinstaller.org/#pyinstaller-quickstart)) to create a single executable file and place the config file in the same folder.
be able to work with the `app.exe.config` files on a per project basis.

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```

this will create a `dist` folder inside your current working directory with an exe file (script.exe) and there you can place your `script.exe.config` file which will parse upon running `script.exe`