# Python for .NET: How to explicitly create instances of C# classes using different versions of the same DLL?

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net, pythonnet

I have a .cs file like

```
namespace SomeNamepace
{


    public struct SomeStruct
    {
        ....
    }

    public static class SomeClass
    {
        ....
    }
```

So far I use it with PythonNET like

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('c:\\Test\Module.dll')
from SomeNamepace import SomeClass, SomeStruct

SomeClass.SomeMethod(...)
```

My problem is now that I need to work with dlls with
identical names and no version number set, so PythonNET will
not see them as two different dlls but as the same.
Even if I import them using the full path with AddReference.

Now I would like to use them explicitly as stated here:

[Python for .NET: Using same .NET assembly in multiple versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408391/python-for-net-using-same-net-assembly-in-multiple-versions)

like

```
lib = clr.AddReference('c:\\Test\Module.dll')
```

I tried a lot of things to create an instance of `SomeClass` like

```
lib.SomeNamespace.SomeClass()
```

or

```
import System
System.Activator.CreateInstance(lib.GetType('SomeNamespace.SomeClass'))
```

or using the the methods `Initialize` or `CreateInstance`

or as mentioned in the link below

```
from System import Type
type1 = lib.GetType('SomeNamespace.SomeClass')
constructor1 = type1.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
```

In the end everything failed, something not found, has no method, etc. etc.

What would be the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify if this concerns IronPython or python.net?

Comment: Python.net. Sorry, I thought IronPython was using python.net in the background. Tag removed.

Comment: And this works quite fine when you have version number associated with both of them? Also does the reflection part works when you have just one library loaded?

Comment: No, nothing of the above worked. However, I found a solution. Will post it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an old [mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2003-October/000007.html) conversation that might explain it

> Things get a lot more complicated if you need to load more than one
>   version of a particular assembly (or more likely, you have a
>   dependency on some library the does so).
>
> In this case, the names you access via the CLR modules will always
>   come from the first version of the assembly loaded (which will always
>   win in the internals of the runtime).

The solution posted there does not work anymore, I guess the .NET function has been depracated. But there is a solution to this. Instead of using PythonNet you must use the .NET framework directly:

```
import System

dll_ref = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath)
print(dll_ref.FullName)
print(dll_ref.Location)
```

Check that the correct DLL is used.

To use multiple DLLs with the same version just load it to another variable

```
another_dll_ref = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(anotherFullPath)
```

Now you can use objects from the specified dll.

**Instance of a public non-static class**

```
some_class_type = dll_ref.GetType('MyNamespace.SomeClass')
my_instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(some_class_type)
my_instance.a = 4 # setting attribute
my_instance.b('whatever') # calling methods
```

**Calling a method in a public static class**

```
some_class_type = dll_ref.GetType('MyNamespace.SomeClass')
method = some_class_type.GetMethod('SomeMethod')
# return type and list of parameters
method.Invoke(None, [1, 2.0, '3'])
```

**Creating a instance of a struct**

```
some_struct_type = dll_ref.GetType('MyNamespace.SomeStruct')
my_struct = System.Activator.CreateInstance(some_struct_type)
my_struct.a = 3
```

From the docs on [LoadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b61s44e8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Use the LoadFile method to load and examine assemblies that have the
>   same identity, but are located in different paths.LoadFile does not
>   load files into the load-from context, and does not resolve
>   dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does.LoadFile
>   is useful in this limited scenario because LoadFrom cannot be used to
>   load assemblies that have the same identities but different paths; it
>   will load only the first such assembly.

**Methods that don't work:**

- adding references to other DLLs with different versions using `dll_ref = clr.AddReference(f)` does not work, even if the file name is specified explicitly and `dll_ref` and Reflection are used to get the methods
- using a longname (like `'MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'` with System.Reflection.Assembly.Load with the version will still use the first version
- `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` does not work with multiple version of the same DLL if an assembly with the same identity is already loaded. LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified. ([Doc LoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx))