# Import of DLL with pythonnet

Tags: python, .net, dll, python.net, pythonnet

I am trying to import and use a DLL in python. Therefore I am using pythonnet.

```
import sys
import clr

sys.path.append('C:\PathToDllFolder')

clr.AddReference('MyDll.dll')
```

However the code yields the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "E:\NET\NET_test.py", line 6, in <module>
>     clr.AddReference('MyDll.dll')
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'MyDll.dll'.
>    bei Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
> ```

Target runtime of the DLL is: v4.0.30319

Is there any way to find out why the import is failing and how i can fix it?

(If necessary i can also provide the DLL)

Comment: Does it make a difference if you omit the `sys.path.append` call and use the full path to the DLL directly within `clr.AddReference`?

Comment: Can you try without extension `.dll`?

Comment: Yes, somehow it works like that (by adding the full path)

Comment: You can find some more info on this in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003112/7919597 You can use `dll_ref = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath)`

Answer (score 5):

This is how it works for me. Dll sits in '/SDK/dll/some_net64.dll'
Note: no .dll extension needed.

```
import os, sys, clr
dll_dir = './SDK/dll/'
dllname = 'some_net64'
path = r'%s%s' % (dll_dir, dllname)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
clr.AddReference(path)
```

Answer (score 5):

clr.AddReference() is bad at describing the error.
A better way to find out why the import fails is to use this.

```
#use this section of code for troubleshooting
from clr import System
from System import Reflection
full_filename = r'C:\foo\bar\MyDll.dll'
Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(full_filename)   #this elaborate the error in details
```

One possibility is that the system knows that your DLL is downloaded from somewhere else (even Dropbox sync counts) and does not allow you to use that DLL file. In that case, you can download a tool from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams
and run this command to remove all those flags from the DLL file.

```
stream -d MyDll.dll
```

After that, the import with clr.AddReference() should work.

Comment: Genius! how could you know that? this 'streams' trick did the work for me! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In python strings `"\"` is an escape character.  To have truly a backslash character in a python string, you need to add a second one: `"\\"`.

Change `sys.path.append('C:\PathToDllFolder')` to `sys.path.append('C:\\PathToDllFolder')`.

I am not sure about `clr.AddReference('MyDll.dll')`, the version without .dll should work: `clr.AddReference('MyDll')`

Answer (score 0):

use absolute path to your dll

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'C:\PathToDllFolder\MyDll.dll')
```

Comment: Please fix your path on Windows" `clr.AddReference(r'C:\PathToDllFolder\MyDll.dll')` or `clr.AddReference('C:\\PathToDllFolder\\MyDll.dll')`.

Comment: Or another (and better IMHO) way is to prefix path strings with "r" (meaning raw). This way you don't have to do things like double backslashes. In this example, it would be clr.AddReference( r'C:\PathToDllFolder\MyDll.dll' )