# Python for .NET - Create an instance of a singelton

Tags: c#, python

I'm trying to use python to create an instance of a singleton class. The class looks like this:

```
public sealed class Test
{
    private Test()
    {

    }

    public static Test GetInstance()
    {
       .......
    }
}
```

I've tried everything from here:

[Python for .NET: How to explicitly create instances of C# classes using different versions of the same DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942487/python-for-net-how-to-explicitly-create-instances-of-c-sharp-classes-using-dif)

How can I create an instance of this class in python?

Comment: You can´t. It´s what a singleton is about: the framework guarantees that there´s ever only a single instance existing. So either don´t use singletons, or use that single instance using `Test.GetInstance()`.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand now. I just want to create one instance and that with Python. Maybe I did not explain it well. I created an API with C #. This should also be usable with Pyhton. That should work.

Comment: it doesn't matter `clr.AddReference('Assemblypath') from Namespace import Test
Test.GetInstance()` would work

Comment: Not in my case. "from Namespace import" i get allways the error "No module named Namespace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
#set reference
ref = clr.AddReference(r'Assemblypath')

#get type 
testType= ref.GetType('Namespace.Test')

#GetUninitializedObject
testUninitialize=System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(testType);

#Now it's possible to call the method
test = testUninitialize.GetInstance()
```